# TreeView items disappear

Tags: wpf, xaml, treeview

I have a TreeView that is generated in code, and will look like this in the end:

```
<TreeView>
  <TreeViewItem Header="X">
    <TreeViewItem Header="Y">
      <TreeViewItem Header="Z">
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock Width="100" Text="SomeText" /><TextBox Width="100" Text="TextInBox" />
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
          <TextBlock Width="100" Text="SomeText" /><TextBox Width="100" Text="TextInBox" />
        </StackPanel>
      </TreeViewItem>
    </TreeViewItem>
  </TreeViewItem>
</TreeView>
```

The problem is, that when you expand this tree fully and then mark the innermost TreeViewItem (in this case) "Z", the TextBlock is invisible until you click on one of the other items. What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you have a theme/skin/style problem - the active treeviewitem's color covers the textboxes. - Try loading a different .xaml theme/skin (e.g. aero from MSDN).

MSDN link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa972144.aspx

Comment: OK, got it now. Setting Foreground="Black" on the TextBlock solved the issue. Thanks